# How to set default fields other than _source in Kibana 4?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have probably 3-5 fields that should show up in the default results in Kibana 4.  The problem is that when I reload the UI it always goes back to the default of _source, which isn't super fun.

Is there a way I can set the default fields?

Comment: We have the same issue. We logged a GH issue here:  https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3392

Comment: This issue also looks related: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2964 the patch he has here might work for you